# Suggestion for the help center/tour

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

I'm a fairly new user, and as such I made sure to read the help center and take the tour.   Since doing that and spending more time on the exchanges I've found more features that actually aren't listed in the help center even *IF* they're searched for by proper name.  So, I'd like to make a suggestion about the tour/help center, the short version I'd like to have them included in.    My suggestion would be to incorporate this into the "Take a tour" section:

Underneath the "Unlock badges for special achievements"

Cut off the remained and replace it with a "Next" button.  The next button goes into the "Help Center" with a 
dialog window advising users to read  The Code of Conduct (with everything else greyed out), once that's read
the help center return and prompts the user to read "Expected Behavior", "Asking", "Answering", & "Reputation and Moderation".
Just after Reputation and Moderation is read, the Privileges window pops up with a heading like " See what earning a good reputation in the community can do for you !
  THE dialog window would end  here with a "NEXT" button visible.  On the next page add back in the end of /tour window   "See new questions", "Ask a question" , "Visit the help center",along with the banner stating  _____ Stack  Exchange is part of the Stack Exchange network.

The tour would end there and a new category would be added into the help center called "Tips" with linked sections like:

Access our API directly at: http://api.stackexchange.com
It's documented at:  http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/

Be sure to check our blog for updates and new features at: https://stackoverflow.blog/

Each Stack exchange has it's own chat site, however  you need at least a 20 reputation to speak on it (chat.(your exchange name).stackexchange.com )

Get to know your fellow users at: https://stackoverflow.com/users

Site analytics are available (You need a 25000 rep to use it however) at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/site-analytics
(a simpler version is readily accessible at: https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#technology-newest )

First, just about none of this information is readily available, I had to find this while reading different parts of the stack exchange.
Pretty much ANY coder would want to know about the API and the docs that went with it, and again, no information about the api comes up even if it's searched for in the help center.

The blog IS listed as a link at the bottom, but drawing more attention to it would also help newer users to learn more about the site, see what's new to the site and what the goals of the site are from the developers themselves

This would be especially pertinent given [this post over at the stackexchange blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/).  This suggestion would be a step in that direction by showing more of what we can offer in a quicker and easier format.

Comment: Someone needs to explain to me why this post is so heavily downvoted.

Comment: None of this information is needed by a new user. An experienced user can find the information in better places. This helps nobody and takes time away from other BTS work.

Comment: The Help Center surfacing isn't a terrible idea per se, but a bit long-winded for a quick tour. Mentioning e.g. API, blog, etc is utterly unnecessary. 99.9% of users never need to know the API exists. If they *do* need to know about it, they need to have the site mastery to find the existing information, which is not exactly carefully hidden.

Answer (score 1):

> My suggestion would be to incorporate this into the "Take a tour" section:
>
> Underneath the "Unlock badges for special achievements", cut off the remainder and replace it with a "Next" button.

Rather than a "Next" button there is a 'what to do next' ***section*** which offers "Help" as one of three choices.

True, a "guided tour" might be offered but it's not, just a 'user customizable' tour, which is thought to be a better option:

[image: Non-Guided Tour Finale]

If the user elects to take the "[Visit the Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help)" route they arrive at the main page of the help.

> The next button goes into the "Help Center" with a dialog window advising users to read "The Code of Conduct" (with ***everything*** **else greyed** out), ...

We are less forceful than that, the path one takes is less fixed, more open. Should people desire help then front and center we have:

[image: Help Center]

The better ([be nice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users?)) approach was chosen over the '[require Tour Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322249/should-and-could-we-require-the-tour-badge-and-or-rep-to-give-answers)' approach.

We don't have bouncers or greeters at the door, we let everyone in.

Just in case, security is hiding in the wings; ready to act if necessary.

Your additional suggestions (questions?) apply to advanced users and it's not thought you'll need to learn everything in the first month (or year). As the first two buttons in the first image above suggest, see what's going on and ask a question if you wish. If something goes wrong new users (should) receive a friendly comment; unless they are quite out of line.